# Complexification of the inclusion $\text{U}_n\subset \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

What is the map $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C}) \to \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C}) \times \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ named in the title? I guess it has something to do with the polar decomposition, but I can't manage to write down something that looks algebraic (which of course the sought-after map must be). Part of the trouble is that I don't understand how complexification is functorial in general.

Comment: it's just the diagonal map $A\mapsto(A,A)$

Comment: That's nice and simple, but why?

Comment: it's a general thing: if $X$ is a complex variety (or whatever is the right generality), $\sigma:X\to X$ an anti-analytic involution (so I'd better write $\sigma:X\to\bar X$ and see it as analytic), $Y$ the set of fixed points of $\sigma$, i.e. $X$ is a/the complexification of $Y$, then $(id,\sigma):X\to X\times\bar X$ is the complexification of $Y\to X$. ...

Comment: ... Now it depends on how you identify $\overline{GL_n(\mathbb{C})}$ with $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. If by $\sigma$ ($\sigma(A)={A^*}^{-1})$ then you get my answer. If by complex conjugation, then we get rather $A\mapsto (A,{A^T}^{-1})$, which is probably a better answer.